# How to Tell if Click Came from Google Search

Tags: web

I'd like to know if there is a way to detect whether the user has entered the website from an Organic Link from Google on certain key words?

What I am trying to do is provide additional information to appear to those who found my site via Google?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Sign up for an account and just add a small snippet of Javascript to your site.  It's really easy to set up and track links from google and even the exact search terms used!